# ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt in VB.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

Hello I have problem with vb.net, when I click that button, it always show error

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy
>   with results for another hstmt

Anyone can help me?

```
Private Sub cmbposting_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbposting.Click

    cmd = New OdbcCommand("select * from stok_master where stok_cd='" & txtstok_cd.Text & "'", conn)
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    rd.Read()
    If rd.HasRows Then
        Dim kurangistok As String = "Update stok_master set " & _
        "qty='" & rd.Item(6) - Val(txtreqqty.Text) & "' " & _
        "where stok_cd='" & txtstok_cd.Text & "'"
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(kurangistok, conn)
        **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()**
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: whats your database?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/119023)

> When accessing an SQL Server database as an ODBC data source in Visual
>   Basic versions 3.0 or 4.0 with the Microsoft Access version 2.0
>   Compatibility Layer installed, error message 3146 may occur:
>
> `ODBC-call failed. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt [#0]`
>
> This error is the result of the SQL Server ODBC driver. The driver can
>   only handle one active statement at a time. The statement remains
>   active until all the rows are fetched.

You can possibly complete reading all the rows, load it to a `DataTable` and then iterate through it to update the table again.

Something like

```
var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var dataTable = new DataTable();

dataTable.Load(dataReader);
```

And then iterate through the `dataTable` like

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
   .......
}
```